# Facebook getSession returns null on heroku

Tags: php, facebook, heroku

I have 3 FB apps running the same code.

There is one master app that runs code locally. There is a first test app, that also runs code locally. And there is a third app that runs the same code but on a Heroku instance.

The 2 first works perfectly while the app running on a Heroku instance fails.

```
if (!$this->session) {
  $this->helper = new FacebookCanvasLoginHelper();
  try {
    $this->session = $this->helper->getSession();  # $this->helper->getSession() always return null when executed on heroku.
    $_SESSION['facebook_session'] = serialize($this->session);

  } catch (FacebookRequestException $e) {
    scratch\Log::write($e->getMessage(), 'FacebookRequestException');

  } catch (\Exception $e) {
    scratch\Log::write($e->getMessage(), 'Exception');
  }
}
```

The helper seems perfectly fine:

```
["signedRequest":protected] => object(Facebook\Entities\SignedRequest)#6 (2) {
  ["rawSignedRequest"] => string(188) "-Wlk-ju826ayyG3koaoy462wAs1AtJCyZ3iH6oJsDog.eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiIsImlzc3VlZF9hdCI6MTQwOTkzMTk3OCwidXNlciI6eyJjb3VudHJ5IjoiZnIiLCJsb2NhbGUiOiJmcl9GUiIsImFnZSI6eyJtaW4iOjIxfX19"
  ["payload"] => array(3) {
    ["algorithm"] => string(11) "HMAC-SHA256"
    ["issued_at"] => int(1409931978)
    ["user"] => array(3) {
      ["country"] => string(2) "fr"
      ["locale"] => string(5) "fr_FR"
      ["age"] => array(1) {
        ["min"] => int(21)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The issue I encounter is specific to the deployment on Heroku. I tried to set on Heroku a FB app previously working fine with local server, it fails as well.

Any hints welcome! :)

---

EDIT: Change the comment in the code sample to make it clearer to readers.

Comment: Is the `serialize()` call returning null (and are you verifying that), or are you simply not getting back session data on the next request?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. What is actually always `null` is not the call to `serialize()` but `$this->session` or more directly  `$this->helper->getSession()`.

Comment: Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685659/facebook-sdk-unable-to-get-session ?

Comment: Yes, I've seen pretty much all related questions suggested by SO, or found through some researches,… The thing everything works just fine when running the app on my local server (works fine with test users as well). It just doesn't work when running on Heroku.

I'll keep looking toward this JS Authentication thing. Who knows…